# Struggling With NSWindowController window Outlet

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, interface-builder

I'm sure this is a really simple problem but I am pulling my hair out over it!

I have a subclass of NSWindowController called WinAController. This has been created in IB and is in MainMenu.xib.

I have a separate nib called WinA.xib that contains just a single window. In this nib, I have set the following:

1. Class of File's Owner to `WinAController`
2. The `window` property of File's Owner to WinA
3. WinA's delegate to `WinAController` (which implements the NSWindowDelegate protocol).

I have hooked up a menu item on MainMenu to the `-showWindow` method of WinAController so that when clicked, WinA should display but nothing happens. It seems that WinAController's `window` property is not being set.

Where am I going wrong? Do I need to initialise WinAController with WinA.xib at some point in code in order to set this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This, called from WinAController, seems to work perfectly:

```
- (id)init {
// Load our window from the nib
self = [super initWithWindowNibName:@"WinA"];

// Now we're initialised - return us
return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Garry - I was having a similar problem with a dialog using the code in your answer above. I could get the dialog to display once, but it was never visible again after that (I had a simple test app with a window with a button to display the dialog). I kept seeing answers with "connect the window outlet on your File's Owner object to the window in your nib", but could not figure out how to do it. That sounds like part of what you are asking.

Here is what I figured out: Along with your solution, you also need to follow the steps at this link - [Connect Window Controller Outlet to Window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9088339/connect-window-controller-outlet-to-window/9097751#9097751)